# How to use one package manager for backend and frontend? (Yarn/NPM)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg

Previously I would use NPM for server side stuff and Bower for frontend. NPM would install to the `node_modules/` directory and I had a `.bowerrc` to install those packages to `public/lib`.

Now I've begun to use Yarn instead of NPM; and since they are pretty much 1:1 compatible it has been a smooth change.. However, now I'm wondering if I can ditch Bower and just use Yarn for everything. But I do not see a way (in either NPM or Yarn) to install normal packages to node_modules, but then have a sort of separate option to put some packages in `public/`... Something similar to the `--dev` option but instead it would be `yarn add jquery --public`. Does anything like this exist?

One option, of course, would be to install all packages to the `public/` directory but I believe this is a bad practice (correct me if I'm wrong).

Another option might be to have a separate `package.json` in the `public/` folder and run separate Yarn commands in there for frontend packages, but it's just a bit less convenient, I think; more error prone.

Comment: Personally I would separate the public folder from the backend folder and manage the dependencies separately. This will give you a better overview of the dependencies per 'project'

Comment: If you use build tools like grunt/gulp to concat/minify your stuff then you can install using npm and point your grunt config to `node_modules`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The norm pretty much is something like:

1. Install packages via `yarn`
2. Use a task runner such as [`gulp`](https://gulpjs.com/), or module loader & bundler such as [`webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/) to create the bundles you need.

   - This all depends on your stack, there are obviously others, for example in the past I've used .NET's native bundling, which you can achieve the same as gulp/webpack... again this is for you to decide.

> The gist of it is, install all the modules in a central place (**using a package manager)**, then
>   have a **loader or other process grab and move** the required assets to the location that you need to use them.

I'd suggest having a look at a kickstart project (pertaining to the stack that you're using) eg: I've used :
[Fountainjs](https://github.com/FountainJS/fountainjs.github.io) in the past with success, or look into [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) if fountain doesnt strike your fancy (fyi. Fountain is built on top of Yeoman)

In pseudo commands:

```
1. yarn install     /// installs all assets
2. gulp build       /// cleans out current public folder, bundles & copies new
3. gulp serve       /// runs your app
```