# Separating Frontend & Backend Dependencies with Gulp/Yarn

Tags: node.js, gulp, yarnpkg

I want to use `yarn` instead of `bower` + `npm`. Yarn uses package.json and does not separate between frontend and backend packages.

I read so far, that I need to separate my frontend + backend dependencies with gulp:
[How to use one package manager for backend and frontend? (Yarn/NPM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775214/how-to-use-one-package-manager-for-backend-and-frontend-yarn-npm)

My app uses the MEAN stack. Currently, I'm using e.g. `wiredep` to inject all frontend dependencies into my `index.html`.

Question:
How can I automatically separate the frontend dependencies from the backend dependencies in my build process?/Is there any option to specify frontend/backend packages with yarn?

Comment: There is no way to separate them because Yarn is unaware of 'frontend' and 'backend', it doesn't really differ from NPM in this regard. There is no urge to separate them as long as you explicitly list the packages in frontend app, e.g. with imports. Even then, it makes sense to keep frontend and backend as different projects, e.g. they may need different package versions. They usually have nothing in common except that frontend build should be copied to backend `public`.

Comment: How does this work with nested dependencies? So far I have only seen them with my backend dependencies not the front end but I guess there are some. Seems a lot of effort to define them manually. I hoped there was a tool which scans my angular depenencies and copies/moves the dependencies automatically into a new folder. Then I could inject the dependencies again with wiredep.

Comment: The most reasonable solution I have seen so far is to separate the fe/be into two projects with each having their own package.json

Comment: That's how it's often done. Sometimes I have 3 projects, a common project hosts both f/e and b/e projects, just to contain code that is common to them and build/deployment scripts that build both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me introduce [handpick](https://github.com/henryruhs/handpick) that lets you target and filter multiple dependencies. I wrote this to speed up CI stages that just need a fragment of the devDependencies but there are eventually more usecases. This project is quite experimental - please leave some feedback.

### Installation

Install on your system:

```
npm install handpick --global
```

### Usage

Run the command:

```
handpick [options]

-V, --version
-T, --target
-F, --filter
-M, --manager
-P, --path
-h, --help
```

### Examples

Define unofficial dependencies inside `package.json` file:

```json
{
    "lintDependencies":
    {
        "eslint": "6.8.0"
    },
    "testDependencies":
    {
        "mocha": "7.1.1"
    }
}
```

Install the `lintDependencies`:

```
handpick --target=lintDependencies
```

Install the `devDependencies` and `lintDependencies` via YARN:

```
handpick --target=devDependencies --target=lintDependencies --manager=yarn
```

Install the `devDependencies` without `testDependencies`:

```
handpick --target=devDependencies --filter=testDependencies
```

Install the `dependencies` and `devDependencies` within path:

```
handpick --path=../shared
```